# AllJoyn Thin Client - Building the services samples on Linux

Tags: linux, alljoyn, thin-client

I have tried to build the service samples AllJoyn Thin Client on Linux but I'm getting an error. Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

The problem is probably in one file called Debug.h, which is missing.

The prompt returns this message: Service.h:20:23: fatal error: qcc/Debug.h: No such file or directory.

More information can be observed on the image: [Debug.h error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPe4h.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are building the wrong services with AJTCL. Try to build under the `services/base_tcl`directory, which is the thin services base directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked.

However, now we are trying to build the complete service sample (AC Server) and we are getting na error.
I would be more than thankful if you help us again.

There the problem goes:

[.....] LINUX:~/Documentos/respositorio/service/base_tcl/test/ACServer$ scons WS=off AJ_TCL_ROOT=../../../../core/ajtcl

scons: *** No SConstruct file found.
File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 905, in_main